# Setting for attribute of a label element with object oriented method

Tags: jquery, label, for-attribute

Labels have a 'for' attribute which makes them point to a certain input field. I need to change the value of this attribute with JQuery so I could use:

```
$("label").attr("for", "targetName");
```

But I also need to set the className, so i'd prefer to use:

```
$("label").attr({
    for: "targetName",
    className: "something" 
});
```

You might allready notice the problem, for is ofcourse a keyword in javascript. Does anybody know how I could solve this? Currently i'm using the first method to set the for and the second to set several other attributes, it works but it's not really pretty.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could also use htmlFor instead of for:

```
$("label").attr({
    htmlFor: "targetName",
    className: "something" 
});
```

Comment: Never heard of that before. Is it standard? Are there any others like that?

Comment: Take a look at: http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-1-20000929/level-one-html.html#ID-13691394

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I prefer to use the .attr({ key: value}) method as I use it in all my code but the for was a problem. Now it's consistent with the rest of my code again, thanks!

Comment: While it does appear in the link on w3.org, this didn't work for me in Chrome (version 29.0.1547.76 m). cletus's  did, however.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using string keys:

```
$("label").attr({
  'for': "targetName",
  'className': "something"
});
```

?

Comment: Mind boggling how easy it sometimes is.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
$("label").attr("for", "targetName").attr("class", "something")
```

OR

```
$("label").attr("for", "targetName").addClass("something")
```

OR

```
$("label").attr({ "for": "targetName", className: "something" });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
$("label").attr("for","targetName").attr("class","something");
```