# JavaScript createElement qn

Tags: javascript, dom

Why doesn't this piece of code work?
When I used the commented part instead of the table it works...
Use table why cannot work?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function addLine() {
            var p = document.createElement('p');
            p.innerHTML = "hello";
            document.getElementById("addline").appendChild(p);
        }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!--
    <input type="submit" value="New Line" onClick="addLine()"/>
    <div id="addline"></div>
    -->
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>inside a table</tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr><input type="submit" value="New Task" onClick="addLine()"/></tr>
                <tr id="addline"></tr>
            </tfoot>                        
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't ask two questiosn in the same question. Ask them in separate questions.

Comment: Cos they are considered minor issues, so i thought it would be better to ask them together....

Comment: Came back and see you haven't (yet) asked the follow-up, so I'll just post the answer here: Use `htmlFor` instead (`a.htmlFor = 'name';`): http://blog.studiosedition.com/2009/11/label-for-attribute/ (And it would be a duplicate question anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232579/setting-for-attribute-of-a-label-element-with-object-oriented-method )

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to append a `<p>` element to `<tr>` element, but only `<td>` and `<th>` elements are allowed there.

Comment: Not if he uncomments the commented-out part, as he said he does when it stops working. Then it's indeterminate whether he's trying to append to a `div` or a `tr`.

Comment: No, he said when he uses that **instead** of the table it **does** work (since a p may be a child of a div).

Comment: Yeah, it's right there in B&W. Need another cup of coffee. :-(

Answer (score 1):

you can only append into <td>...

Instead of:

```
<tr id="addline"></tr>
```

Use:

```
<tr><td id="addline"></td></tr>
```

For the second question, "for" is a reserved Keyword in many languages.  You can't use it, and  if you find a way to do so [setAttribute or something like that, not that I've tested that, i'm just throwing a wild guess] its bad programming practice.

Maybe you can use variable name "isFor" or "usage" =/ idk

Comment: It's not bad practice to use `a.setAttribute('for')`. At that point he's specifying the name of an attribute, which has nothing to do with JavaScript's reserved keywords (and which he *has* to do if he wants to set that attribute on the element).

Comment: why <tr><td id="addline"></td></tr> works but <tr id="addline"></tr>
don't?

Comment: Then why 'label1.for = "aaa"' can't be used if it is not the case of reserve word?

Comment: @yeeen — for the reasons I described in my answer, and because it *is* a reserved word, respectively.

Comment: ok, got it... cos when i read urs i don't understand, when i saw itz's, i forgot abt urs... sorry for the trouble..

Comment: @yeeen : Basically, in HTML "tr" starts a table row.  "td" starts a table cell.   When you have a table, you're not writing into a row, you're writing into a cell.  That is the logic you should follow.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Re my comment above: It's not bad practice, but it doesn't work on IE6 or IE7. You were on the right track, it's `htmlFor`: `a.htmlFor = 'name';`. So that goes on the list along with `cssFloat` and `className`. :-)